# User model not authenticating, but superuser does? in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have made a superuser through createsuperuser from the command line. I have created the following user class.

```
class Teacher(AbstractUser):
    """ User model """
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

I then create a user through the admin screen; but when I want to authenticate using the following code; it user always returns none. except when I use the superuser account.

```
def loginview(request):
    """Creates Login Screen"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        # Authenticate User via Django login system.
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        print(user)
        if user is not None:
            # Confirm credentials are correct.

            auth_login(request, user)
            return render(request, "score_board/points.html")
        else:
            return render(request, "score_board/loginview.html",
                          {"message": "Wrong username/password!"})
    else:
        return render(request, "score_board/loginview.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have not updated your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` variable in `settings.py`, when you're running `python manage.py createsuperuser` django will use it's [built-in User model](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L389)

In your above code snippet, you're defining a new `Teacher` model that inherits from `AbstractBaseUser` (behaving similar to Django's `User` model), but you are not overriding `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings file. Hence, Django will look in the same table (`auth.User`) when calling `authenticate()` (more context [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L36))

Comment: I have ```AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'score_board.Teacher'``` in my settings.py. Is this what you were referring to?

Problem therefore, still exists. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: Yes. Share a lil bit more info regarding this, as in: what does `print(user)` return?

Comment: if I use the superuser, it returns: ```admin, , ```
If I use any other account made in the admin screen, it returns ```None```

Comment: Either it doesn't look in the right table (auth.User vs. Teacher) or one of the following conditions is not met: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L36

Comment: I think it might be something to do with the passwords. As when I create the user it doesn't hash any of the passwords. When I make a superuser it does. Any ideas from that?